# Appropriate UIImage size on iPhone 6

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimageview, uiimage, png

I got two PNG files:

- 568x320.png
- 667x375.png

If I'm creating UIImageView:

```
UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"568x320.png"]];
```

and run this in iOS Simulator > iPhone 5/5s/6 (iOS 8.1) image covers full screen (even on iPhone 6). On the other hand if I'm creating UIImageView:

```
UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"667x375.png"]];
```

and run above in iOS Simulator > iPhone 6 (iOS 8.1) image is bigger than screen. What's wrong?

PS. I'm not using Storyboard (everything programatically)

PS2. No constraints were added.

Comment: Did you add the needed iPhone 6 launch image or the Launch Screen file? Without those, the iPhone 6 runs an app in zoomed mode.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have appropriate iPhone 6/6+ launch images in your project?  If you do not, the simulator is going to assume you don't support iPhone 6.  In that case, iPhone assumes you are scaling the app up to run on those platforms.  So when you create the 667x375 image, it's larger than the "screen" iPhone is assuming.

This is how apps that haven't been updated to support iPhone 6 / 6+ look ok when they run on an actual device.

Try including the appropriate Default images and I believe your problem will go away.

Comment: Including the appropriate Default images do the trick. Unfortunately I can't vote up for the answer because I do not have enough reputation.